# Button background colour

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I need to change the `background` colour of a button using C# code (Visual Studio 2008).

I saw some people recommending the inclusion of a directive: `using System.Windows.Media`;  - I tried it and it triggered this error: Windows does not exist in `namespace System`. I tried several combinations like:

```
 btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
 btn.Background = Brushes.Green;
```

And neither is working. Is a special directive needed for using colour? What code do you suggest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you on windows forms or WPF?

Comment: Where are you running your code?  Is this winforms, wpf or asp.net?

Comment: It's ASP.NET, John, just added the tag.

Comment: This may help ... http://asp-net-example.blogspot.ca/2009/03/how-to-set-change-button-backcolor.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should change your button background color to Red

```
yourButtonName.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

You need to include **System.Drawing** namespace as Color class belongs to that. Like this

```
using System.Drawing;
```

And ofcourse you need to add the reference to `System.Drawing` DLL in your project to use this namespace and Color class.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Drawing;
```

allows you to use

```
Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
button.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Answer (score 0):

Although that property is technically available to all WebControls, it ***may*** be ignored for buttons (I haven't confirmed).  This, of course, is assuming your project is ASP.NET.  Having said that, if it DOES happen to work for you, I highly advise that you test this in other browsers as it may be MS specific.

From MSDN:

> This property will render for only certain controls. For example,
>   Table, Panel, DataGrid, Calendar, and ValidationSummary will render
>   this property. It will also work for CheckBoxList, RadioButtonList and
>   DataList if their RepeatLayout property is RepeatLayout.Table, not
>   RepeatLayout.Flow.

Source: [WebControl.BackColor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.backcolor)

However, a more flexible and widely practiced method of achieving this is to use CSS.

Answer (score -1):

On PageLoad try this,

`Button1.Style.Add("background-color", "green");`

Use a method to write a condition when you want to change the color of the button. if condition is true use above code to change the color of the button as you prefer.