# How do I use a string variable to set an html control color

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to set the colors of my controls on my webpage to be variables.  For example I would store a value of "#000000" in a database and when the page loads it would put that value in the original html tag. So `<asp:Button ID="btnTesta" runat="server" Text="Button" ForeColor='<% MYVALUE%>'  />`.

Comment: you using a sql datasource and a datalist or something? Why aren't you setting the forecolor property in the code behind?

Comment: It may be because I am not too knowledgeable on the subject but thought if i set all the properties to certain colors in the code behind it would take longer to load.  Doesn't it load the entire page before it runs the back end code? The values would usually be the same everytime it loads so I was just trying to find the most efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign value from code behind.

```
btnTesta.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("yourvaluefromdatabase");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should change your button background color or ForeColor color

```
yourButtonName.BackColor = Color.Red;
yourButtonName.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

You need to include **System.Drawing** namespace as Color class belongs to that. Like this

```
using System.Drawing;
```

And ofcourse you need to add the reference to `System.Drawing` DLL in your project to use this namespace and Color class.

[image]

Refrence [Button background colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055414/button-background-colour)