# BackgroundColor change in C#

Tags: c#, web

i am trying to change the BackgroundColor of a Button

```
BtnColo = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#48BCB4");
btnAdd.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#48BCB4");
```

But it 's not working properly

Comment: what you mean by `but it not working properly` What kind of application is this

Comment: The color remain as it is without any change

Comment: Is it a Windows application or WPF application?

Comment: it is web application

Comment: Your both statements are working in winforms.Where you have written these statements? Do they really get executed?

Comment: Those statements are in button click event and executed without throwing exception but the button color remain as it is

Comment: I just want to change button background color after clicking that button in my web application

Comment: First Tag your question correctly.  are you using any sort of threading??

Comment: Can you add what is BtnColo is all about?

Comment: Try to debug the code to ensure if these statements get executed as you may have broken event binding. Adding complete related code would clear the situation.

Comment: Add relavent details and the code block. With the above pseudocode you will not get the correct solution for your query

Comment: Does the page get refreshed on your click? Do you post/submit anything?

Answer (score 0):

This should change your button background color to Red

```
yourButtonName.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

You need to include **System.Drawing** namespace as Color class belongs to that. Like this

```
using System.Drawing;
```

And ofcourse you need to add the reference to `System.Drawing` DLL in your project to use this namespace and Color class.

[image]

[Reference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055414/button-background-colour)